# Where can I find information on getting started creating Skins for Flex/AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air, skins

I don't have any experience with creating Skins, but I have the tools to do it (Fireworks, etc.). I'm used to doing as much as I can with styles, but, I want to break out of the mold and start using Skins more, especially so that the look and feel of my apps can be ported to other platforms. Where do I get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/skinning_components/

http://flashenabledblog.com/2008/06/27/tutorials-developing-extending-and-styling-flex-components/

Answer (score 1):

You can find more Adobe Flex skins here: [scalenine.com](http://www.scalenine.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is really what I was looking for: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/skins_styles.html

Answer (score 0):

Juan Sanchez and Andy McIntosh just released a great book covering skinning and general UI prettification in detail:

[Creating Visual Experiences with Flex 3.0](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fs%3Fie%3DUTF8%26x%3D0%26ref%255F%3Dnb%255Fss%255Fgw%26y%3D0%26field-keywords%3Dvisial%2520experiences%2520flex%25203%26url%3Dsearch-alias%253Daps&tag=chrtos-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=390957)

I'm about halfway into it and it's definitely worth the read -- skinning can be a huge pain in the butt without good guidance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've also read the Creating Visual Experiences with Flex 3.0 book and give it two thumbs up for what you to want to do. Chapters focus specifically on designing skins in a variety of software, one of which is Fireworks.